# Where Do I Learn the Rest of Oliver's Spells?

Tags: ni-no-kuni-wrath-of-the-white-witch

I'm starting to work towards [**Magic Master**](http://psnprofiles.com/trophy/1806-Ni-no-Kuni-Wrath-of-the-White-Witch/32-Magic-Master):

> Awarded for learning all of Oliver's spells.

Is there a checklist along with places I can learn the remaining spells?  I'm assuming that he doesn't just learn the rest through leveling up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most of the spells you will learn through the playthrough. There are a few spells that you will learn through Horace the sage of the ages. He is the ghost who moves through all the towns asking you riddles and awards you with spells.
Finish his questline to get all the rest of the spells that are not handed to you during the course of the normal storyline.

Here is a link to one of the guides to Horace's Questline - [Horace's Quest](http://www.ign.com/wikis/ni-no-kuni-wrath-of-the-white-witch/Horace_Riddle_Solutions)